# How to make firebase database private?

Tags: android, database, firebase, backend

I have a project in which I use firebase. While working on the project I have changed the read and write rules to true. I have uploaded the project to github. So now random people are forking my project and making changes in my firebase database instead of creating a new firebase database. I want to perform read and write operations on my database, but I don't want anyone else to perfrom the read and write operations apart from me. What shall I do?

Comment: First update the security rules and make it read only.

Comment: If I make it read only...will I be able to update the database?

Comment: No you won't be able to do that. Its just a primary solution. You can also delete the database altogether, and later create a new database that can be accessed by only you.

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#default_rules_locked_mode

Comment: If you're using Firestore, this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404) will help, right?